# Finding the systems connected in local network from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, networking, sharing

I am developing an application which identifies(find) all the systems connected in same network/LAN to share the data.
     could please share with me how to identify(find) the systems which are connected in same network/LAN.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you say all systems, I assume you mean all instances of your application? If so then the correct solution is to use `Bonjour`. Documentation on how to use it can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html). Note that your app needs to be actively running on all the devices that you are trying to discover, since the iPhone does not support background apps.

If you are just talking about finding all other devices in the area then you need to resort to techniques like port scanning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Louis . But "All Systems" means all local computers in that network to access files.